# Is there a way to check if a query hit a cached result or not in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are performance tuning, both in terms of cost and speed, some of our queries and the results we get are a little bit weird. First, we had one query that did an overwrite on an existing table, we stopped that one after 4 hours. Running the same query to an entirely new table and it only took 5 minutes. I wonder if the 5 minute query maybe used a cached result from the first run, is that possible to check? Is it possible to force BigQuery to not use cache?

Comment: never mind, I did find the checkbox on how to force BigQuery to not use cache.

Comment: You can also use info schema to see whether it hits the cache or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run query in UI - expand Options and make sure Use Cached Result properly set
Also, in UI, you can check Job Details to see if cached result was used

If you run your query programmatically - you should use respective attributes - [configuration.query.useQueryCache](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.useQueryCache) and [statistics.query.cacheHit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#statistics.query.cacheHit)